# What if I erase an undelivered message

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, delete

My questions are concerning Whatsapp.

If I send a message, there are three indicators - one tick,two ticks and two blue ticks. If I delete it when it's still being sent (one tick),will the second side still be able to read it?

By the way, is there an option how to change or delete a message in a short period of time after sending it? (As it is possible at gmail?)

Thanks a lot.

Axessa

Answer (score 1):

1 tick = server received the message. After this you can't stop the message to be sent.

You can stop messages to be sent if you delete them before the first tick appears. If you get lucky you have time for that...or you can try to quickly turn off WiFi/3g but most of the time messages get sent to server too quick for that

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will surely be readable at the destination side if the device is having internet. You can try it by making two android phone at your home.

Try this too.

Get two android phone with whatsapp and then send one message to another phone, but you have to be quick to turn off your net as you send your message , i mean you have to turn off the net before the double click. You will see the message is delivered on the second phone.

Comment: I would recommend another way of testing it: turn off internet on receiver mobile BEFORE you send a message, send a message from the second mobiel, delete one-ticked message and after that turn on the internet on the receiver mobile. This is how you can be sure that one-ticked message was deleted on a sender side before being delivered to a receiver.

Comment: Yeah ! Thats great too ! But I am pretty sure about the one tick message get delivered on other mobile, even if he delete the message on status of one tick.

Answer (score -1):

1 tick means received by server
2 ticks mean received on other phone
2 blue ticks mean read by recipent.

hope this helps.

and no there isn't a way to change a message after sending it.